# Changing Hardware - Fresh OS Install?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I am going to be upgrading my motherboard, memory, and processor and currently I am dual booting Win7 and Ubuntu. Will I need to perform a fresh install or should this be plug and play? The processor is staying AMD and the motherboard is going to stay MSI (if that makes any difference at all) just a little faster on each item.

Answer (score 2):

You may get away with not doing a fresh install but in my experience with any major hardware change like that (motherboard) you should do a clean install.

This will prevent any strange problems that may occur because of conflicting drivers in your current install.

Comment: Agreed...buuuut...i've just recently got into linux and its taken me hours upon hours to configure all my software to work properly, then I decided to upgrade. Is there any way to back up software on linux and do a fresh install, out of curiosity?

Comment: Have a look at: [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) for ubuntu specific questions.

Comment: Here is a link to backing up and restoring your system. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

Answer (score 1):

I clean install is not required. I assume your hard disk is going to remain the same, so the OS boot information is preserved. My suggestion is boot into the OS with the new hardware, uninstall the old drivers before installing the new ones.

From first hand experience, I have switched my hard disk (containing my Windows XP OS) with another machine quite a few times without any issues, though I am not sure of the behavior in Ubuntu.